# What is the value of the ideal value of the generator polynomial index in the Schifra library for Reed-Solomon error correcting code?

Tags: c++, error-correction, reed-solomon

I am trying to use the the [Schifra Reed-Solomon error correcting code library](http://www.schifra.com/example.html) in a project. I have no background about how Reed-Solomon code and Galois field work. I am having trouble figuring out the ideal value of the generator_polynomial_index for a 16 bit symbol(field descriptor).

My code works for the the index 0 and many others. I have tried all values of index. The code works for a lot of them (0-32724 & 32779-65485 to be precise) but

### Questions

1. What is the most ideal value?
2. What is changing if I switch to another value of index(which also works but is not ideal)?

### Rest of my discoveries:

- field_descriptor = symbol size(bits/symbol)
- code_length(Total number of symbols(data symbols + error-correction code symbols)) = 2^symbol_size - 1 (Library only supports this value of code length)
- generator_polynomial_root_count = fec_length(redundancy or number of error-correction symbols)
- Errors are measured in symbols and not bits i.e. 1 incorrect bit in a particular symbol is counted as 1 error. But even if all 16 bits are incorrect; it would count as 1 error(not 16).
- The maximum number of errors and erasures which can be rectified should obey the following inequality: 2*num_errors + num_erasures < fec_length

Please correct me if I am mistaken anywhere

```
const std::size_t field_descriptor                =   16;
const std::size_t generator_polynomial_index      =  index;
const std::size_t generator_polynomial_root_count = 50;

/* Reed Solomon Code Parameters */
const std::size_t code_length = 65535;
const std::size_t fec_length  =  50;
const std::size_t data_length = code_length - fec_length;

/* Instantiate Finite Field and Generator Polynomials */
const schifra::galois::field field(field_descriptor,
schifra::galois::primitive_polynomial_size14, schifra::galois::primitive_polynomial14);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what is the ideal value of the generator_polynomial_index

There probably isn't an "ideal" value.

I had to look at the github code to determine that the generator field index is the log of the first consecutive root of the generator polynomial.

https://github.com/ArashPartow/schifra/blob/master/schifra_sequential_root_generator_polynomial_creator.hpp

Typically the index is 0 (first consecutive root == 1) or 1 (first consecutive root == Alpha (the field primitive)). Choosing index = 1 is used for a "narrow sense" code. It slightly simplifies the Forney Algorithm. Link to wiki article, where "c" represents the log of the first consecutive root (it lists the roots as a^c, a^(c+1), ...):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forney_algorithm

Why use a narrow sense code:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174159/why-should-a-reed-solomon-code-be-a-narrow-sense-bch-code

For hardware, the number of unique coefficients can be reduced by using a self-reciprocal generator polynomial, where the first consecutive root is chosen so that the generator polynomial is of the form:  1 x^n + a x^(n-1) + b x^(n-2) + ... + b x^2 + a x + 1. For 32 roots in GF(2^16), the first consecutive root is alpha^((65536-32)/2) = alpha^32752, and the last consecutive root would be alpha^32783. Note this is only possible with a binary field GF(2^n), and not possible for non-binary fields such as GF(929) (929 is a prime number). The question shows a range for index that doesn't include 32752; if 32752 doesn't work with this library, it's due to some limitation in the library, and not with Reed Solomon error correction algorithms.

Other than these 3 cases, index = 0, 1, or self-reciprocal generator polynomial, I'm not aware of any reason to choose a different index. It's unlikely that the choice of index has any effect on trying to decode beyond the normal limits.

---

> The maximum number of errors and erasures which can be rectified should obey the following inequality: 2*num_errors + num_erasures < fec_length

That should be

```
2*num_errors + num_erasures <= fec_length
```